# Disadvantage of having only accepted papers but no published papers while applying for a postdoc position

Tags: publications, mathematics, journals, postdocs, arxiv

Is there any disadvantage of having only accepted papers but no published papers while applying for a postdoc position? All my papers are in arxiv, where the names of journals where my papers will appear are mentioned. One of the journals has a webpage for upcoming papers, but it seems like the other journal has nothing such.

My research area is in geometry and topology.

Comment: I mean, what are you gonna do about it?

Comment: Honestly, when choosing postdocs I mainly look at reference letters and the arXiv preprints. Everyone understands that publication takes time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter, for papers "to appear" and a fixed publication are equally valuable on your CV.

Sometimes in academia there can be bureaucratic reasons where "accepted" and "published" can make a small difference. But in the context of applying for postdocs it doesn't matter.